# Android AccountManager addAccount from service

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm using an account manager account in a service (which extends FirebaseInstanceIdService). If theres no valid account then I add the account using accountManager.addAccount.

That takes as a parameter activity (which is used for starting the account log-in activity). However as I'm calling addAccount from a service I don't have a current activity to place there. How do I call addAccount from a service and get it to display the account login where needed?

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        Account account[] = accountManager.getAccountsByType(ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        if(account.length==0) {
            Activity activity=???????//What can I set here
            accountManager.addAccount(ACCOUNT_TYPE, AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, null,
            null, activity, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
                        }
                    }, null);
            return null;
        }
        //do stuff with ContentResolver using account
    }
}
```

Comment: edited to show some code to illustrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

`addAccount()` method requires Activity instance to call the default Authenticator Activity.

Their is another method called `addAccountExplicitly()` in AccountManager class. 
Here is the documentation:

```
/**
     * Adds an account directly to the AccountManager. Normally used by sign-up
     * wizards associated with authenticators, not directly by applications.
     * <p>Calling this method does not update the last authenticated timestamp,
     * referred by {@link #KEY_LAST_AUTHENTICATED_TIME}. To update it, call
     * {@link #notifyAccountAuthenticated(Account)} after getting success.
     * However, if this method is called when it is triggered by addAccount() or
     * addAccountAsUser() or similar functions, then there is no need to update
     * timestamp manually as it is updated automatically by framework on
     * successful completion of the mentioned functions.
     * <p>It is safe to call this method from the main thread.
     * <p>This method requires the caller to have a signature match with the
     * authenticator that owns the specified account.
     *
     * <p><b>NOTE:</b> If targeting your app to work on API level 22 and before,
     * AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS permission is needed for those platforms. See docs
     * for this function in API level 22.
     *
     * @param account The {@link Account} to add
     * @param password The password to associate with the account, null for none
     * @param userdata String values to use for the account's userdata, null for
     *            none
     * @return True if the account was successfully added, false if the account
     *         already exists, the account is null, or another error occurs.
     */
    public boolean addAccountExplicitly(Account account, String password, Bundle userdata);
```

**Usage:**

Create Account instance:

```
final Account account = new Account(accountName, intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE));
```

Initialise account metadata:

```
String authtoken = //Generated Auth Token ;
String authtokenType = //Auth Token type;
String accountPassword= //Auth password if available;
```

Call addAccountExplicitly() method:

```
mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, accountPassword, //User data bundle);
mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, authtokenType, authtoken);
```

This will be good to go. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have said that if there are no accounts set up and a new account needs adding I do want the Authentication Activity open for the user to input their credentials. addAccount is ideal when the need for an account occurs within another activity, but I can't work out how to get an activity instance when the need for an account occurs from a service.

Comment: For that I would recommend to start the activity yourself using intent from the service if the array size of accounts is zero. No need to rely on addAccount() method because ultimately your addAccount() method will be called in the Authenticator Activity.